What do you call the number appearing on the front of a bus?
All buses have a number appearing in the front,

What do you call it? Can it be called a sign?
For e.g. the sign on the said 6 Aviation/Imperial. Is it a correct expression? Are there more idiomatic expressions?

Are you talking about the route number (which is 6 in your photo), or the fleet number (which is 7070 in your photo)?

@DawoodibnKareem: the route number, fairly obviously.

The proper name for the whole display is called a destination sign in American English and a destination indicator or destination blind in British English. According to Wikipedia this is also called a headsign. However, while all of the above may be terminology used by transport operators, most people would probably just call it a 'display', 'notice' or 'sign'.
The number you specifically mentioned is the route number, as it denotes a specific numbered route that the bus will take. Again, there might be a slight disparity between the proper name and what most people call it, as you will hear people say "I caught the number 6 bus" which sounds like the number belongs to the bus, but several different vehicles may travel the same numbered route at the same time, so the number doesn't uniquely identify the bus specifically.

Not sure what to call it, but I wouldn't call that display a "sign" and don't think most speakers of American English would call it one either.  A physical sign is fixed in place, mounted on a wall or signpost or some sort of stanchion or horizontal support.

@TimR Wikipedia says it is also called a headsign, so I don't think 'sign' would be so unusual in casual use. I can't think of many situations where one would need to use any of these terms, so anything descriptive should be fine.

Yes, I've never heard anyone use a term for it.  A native AmE speaker would ask "What does that bus say?"

People actually say: The number 6 bus or the number [number] bus. And it is not always a route number at all.

I'll add, as far as I'm aware, all the official names for this display are not well known. Someone who works on the buses would have reason to know and use them, but most ordinary people would just call it the "sign [or 'display', etc.] on the front of the bus."

I would call it the "route sign". Maybe "route label" or "route name." I do think most people would be OK with the term "sign" for that panel of information. I have no idea what the technical or jargon term is for that.

By the way, the bus also has a number on it, "7070," which is probably an equipment number that doesn't change (obviously, it's painted on).

@Lambie I've even heard people omit the "bus" part.  The only thing you could catch in this city is a bus so the reference is clear.  All routes are three digit numbers, also, making it clearer.

Here in Scotland / England I've never heard it called a "blind", rather it would be a "Destination Board" or simply a bus number/route number. The blind of a bus is what the driver uses to prevent glare from the sun.

@MikeB you're maybe not old enough - the term 'blind' is a throwback to when it was a roller that the driver turned to the current route they were on. Now they are a digital display it's probably a dying term, but it is still used according to my colleague who is a bus and train enthusiast.

@Astralbee Ouch, now I feel old. :-/ I didn’t know they were called blinds, but I clearly remember those rollers still being turned by drivers when the bus switched routes at the bus station or directions at the ‘apogee’ of the route (whatever the actual term for that may be), and that was well into the 2000s.

Yes, you can call it a "sign," in that it does display information that helps a passenger determine which bus is the correct one to board. A typical sign will contain two pieces of information. In your specific picture, the designation of 6 indicates a route or line name, and the right displays the final destination for the route.
The route tells you the possible stops, while the destination tells you which direction the bus is headed towards, because buses that go both directions on the same route have the same number. This is especially important at places where the two directions share similar stops (e.g. in a parking lot or bus depot).
Note that I pointed out that 6 is a route name, not a number. While some regions may use numbers exclusively, it is important to know that there may be regional variations. It is always important to consult a route map to be sure that a given bus will take you to your intended destination.
In Denver, there is both a 15 and a 15L. They both have the same terminating destinations. However, the L indicates that the 15L has a limited number of stops, providing shorter overall travel time at the expense of having fewer choices to get off. Similarly, there are routes like the 120X ("X" for Express), small trains called LightRail that are named by letter ("A Line"), or a verb (HOP, SKIP, JUMP), and others, like EV or CV.
However, as far as being idiomatic, English-speakers do not typically say anything so formal as "6 Aviation/Imperial". Having used buses in many places in America, I would say it is idiomatic to use one of three phrases, depending on the route and your position on the route.
If there is only one bus that serves a stop, it can be referred to as just "the bus." If there are multiple buses, you'll typically need to refer to the route name. If there are multiple buses headed each direction, you may also need the destination or direction of travel.
Assuming you're at a bus stop that serves just one bus, you can say "When will the bus get here?" and it will be well-understood. If you want to know if a particular bus serves a stop, one can ask "Does the 15L stop here?" It will be understood that the inquiry is about a route name.
If you know the route, but not the stop, you can ask "Where can I catch the 92?" If you need to know when the next bus arrives at a multiple bus stop, you can ask "When will the 120X get here?" If you ask about how to get to a certain location, someone who knows the routes might say "you can take the 92 to the station, and then transfer to the 0L."
Of course, regions may vary, so you may want to listen to the particular lingo where you are if you travel abroad. There are typically many people at larger bus stops, so you're likely to hear the phrases they use. In general, English speakers tend to omit "obvious" details in speech, so it will sound natural to simply refer to a route by its name, rather than name and destination. Many routes also tend to be referenced by their direction of travel, such as the "westbound 92" or "eastbound 92," rather than their final destination.
In some cases, you may need the destination as well. If there are stops that travel both directions, or cases where the stops are near each other, you may need to be more specific, such as "Where is the stop for the 15 headed West on Colfax?" or "Where do I catch the 0 headed downtown?" This is never necessary at termination points, because the only possible option is to head the direction of the other termination point.
In summary, it should almost never be necessary to use the words "number" or "bus" in reference to navigating public transit, excepting for the general "the bus" phrase used when only one possible bus exists. Of course, you will be perfectly understood if you do use longer grammatical constructions than necessary, but it is likely you would be perceived as someone who's first language is not English.

I used to live in Boulder. Bound + Stampede ftw~ :)


This is never necessary at termination points, because the only possible option is to head the direction of the other termination point.

Some busses have multiple termination points, either due to a forking route, or simply stopping service before the end point.  (Though in the latter case, arguably the bus is still headed for a destination, even if it is not scheduled to provide service to it.

Tokyo busses use an odd naming convention.  They typically start with a character that is often but not always an abbreviation of a major train station served by the bus.  Then, a two-digit number, then sometimes an additional number or second character after that, such as 都05-2 or 東42甲.  甲 is an ordinal meaning "first" of several.  Japan has taken steps to make its other transport more foreigner-friendly and should consider updating the bus names.  Even out-of-town Japanese could be confused by 東 and  都 which both can be read "to".  And yet, the number itself is unique at least in an area.

Are there really places that have buses numbered zero? That seems… weird. // @SwissFrank Surely Japanese people would immediately recognise the difference between 東 tō/tou and 都 to?

@JanusBahsJacquet As I said, the rules depend on the transportation region. In Denver, there is a 0 route. Why? We don't know. The officials of that transportation region choose their own rules.

Surely Japanese people would immediately recognise the difference between 東 tō/tou and 都 to?  In theory, sure.  In practice--in chaotic environments, unknown speaker, just a snippet of speech (e.g. an answer to the question of which bus to take), when you don't know what the kanji are, it's not a sure thing.   Remember numerals are artificially made the same length as well when reading digit by digit too: if read by digits would 都25 be read toniigou or touniigou?  I've been fairly fluent in Japanese since the early 90s and have lived here 20+ years but I'm not positive.

If you need to specifically refer to the physical object, or just want to speak directly, using 'sign' is perfectly appropriate, but you may need to clarify what you mean.
I don't think this 'sign' has a commonly recognised name. I might refer to it as a sign or a display, but I would probably phrase it something like 'the sign on the front of the bus,' or perhaps 'the display with the number and the destination on the front of the bus,' just to be really explicit.
In general I would try to avoid needing to think of an appropriate word by using a phrase like 'the number on the bus.' As a learner you don't need to try to be creative, just be aware that some native speakers might confuse themselves talking about this!
